# How to arrange the lines in ascending order

Tags: sed, awk

I have a folder that contains 200 pdb files.I would like to arrange the atom lines of PDB files in ascending order based on the 6th column. I would like to get in-place editing for each pdb file in the folder. your help would be appreciated.

```
ATOM     81  N   ASN A 248      38.791 -16.708  12.507  1.00 52.04           N 
ATOM     82  CA  ASN A 248      39.443 -17.018  11.206  1.00 54.49           C 
ATOM    422  C   SER A 205      70.124 -29.955   8.226  1.00 55.81           C 
ATOM    423  O   SER A 205      70.901 -29.008   8.438  1.00 46.60           O 
ATOM    303  N   MET A 231      61.031 -38.086  -3.054  1.00 52.32           N 
ATOM    304  CA  MET A 231      60.580 -39.074  -4.047  1.00 64.11           C
ATOM    392  C   GLU B  65      23.248  10.071  -7.321  1.00 48.26           C  
ATOM    393  O   GLU B  65      24.465  10.200  -7.158  1.00 46.53           O
ATOM    394  O   GLU B  65      24.465  10.200  -7.158  1.00 46.53           O
```

Desired output

```
ATOM    392  C   GLU B  65      23.248  10.071  -7.321  1.00 48.26           C
ATOM    393  O   GLU B  65      24.465  10.200  -7.158  1.00 46.53           O
ATOM    394  O   GLU B  65      24.465  10.200  -7.158  1.00 46.53           O 
ATOM    422  C   SER A 205      70.124 -29.955   8.226  1.00 55.81           C  
ATOM    423  O   SER A 205      70.901 -29.008   8.438  1.00 46.60           O 
ATOM    303  N   MET A 231      61.031 -38.086  -3.054  1.00 52.32           N
ATOM    304  CA  MET A 231      60.580 -39.074  -4.047  1.00 64.11           C
ATOM     81  N   ASN A 248      38.791 -16.708  12.507  1.00 52.04           N
ATOM     82  CA  ASN A 248      39.443 -17.018  11.206  1.00 54.49           C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sort`.

```
sort -n -k 6 inputfile
```

`-n` performs numeric sort, and `-k` tells to sort via a key.

EDIT: For in-place sorting, use the `-o` option:

```
sort -n -k 6 inputfile -o inputfile
```

Comment: +1. Alternative form: `sort -k 6n,6 inputfile`. Actually it does not do inplace editing. Try `perl -i`, which does.

Comment: Another alternate: `sort -nk6 inputfile`.

Comment: @devnull  Thank you for your answer. I would like to get in-place editing for multiple files. How can I change your code?

Comment: Thank you! I have a folder that contains 200 pdb files. This code doesn't work for multiple files.

Comment: for multiple files, you can write a script:

`#!/bin/bash
set -- */regex_filename/

for FILE
do
    sort -n -k 6 $FILE -o $FILE
done`

Comment: Or maybe `find . -type f -name "*.pdb" -exec sort -n -k 6 {} -o {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

I use a hash where its key will be the 6th field plus a counter that increments each line appended at the end. This avoids overwrite duplicated entries and keep stable order. Then use `asorti()` function to sort by that 6th field and print each line of the original array.

Content of `script.awk`:

```
{
        ++n
        data[ $6 _ n ] = $0;
}

END {
        asorti( data, mod_data, "@ind_num_asc" )
        l = length( data )
        for ( i = 1; i <= l; i++ ) {
                print data[ mod_data[i] ]
        }
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

That yields:

```
ATOM    392  C   GLU B  65      23.248  10.071  -7.321  1.00 48.26           C  
ATOM    393  O   GLU B  65      24.465  10.200  -7.158  1.00 46.53           O
ATOM    394  O   GLU B  65      24.465  10.200  -7.158  1.00 46.53           O
ATOM    422  C   SER A 205      70.124 -29.955   8.226  1.00 55.81           C 
ATOM    423  O   SER A 205      70.901 -29.008   8.438  1.00 46.60           O 
ATOM    303  N   MET A 231      61.031 -38.086  -3.054  1.00 52.32           N 
ATOM    304  CA  MET A 231      60.580 -39.074  -4.047  1.00 64.11           C
ATOM     81  N   ASN A 248      38.791 -16.708  12.507  1.00 52.04           N 
ATOM     82  CA  ASN A 248      39.443 -17.018  11.206  1.00 54.49           C
```

Comment: @user2374784: You will need the GNU version. Otherwise I think `asorti()` won't work.